# missing grub cannot boot into ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

My system dual booted with windows and ubuntu16.04LTS was working fine but one day when i start my system it shows checking disk errors.. i wait and then it boots into windows directly without giving me any option.. i tried to boot from the boot menu by pressing f12 at the starting but there is no ubuntu option now.. i am sure ubuntu is still present in the partition i have checked that.. i have tried many things available online but none of them seems to work in my case ex: i tried easybcd which says boot is efi mode and therefore i cannot add any linux boot to it.. i also made a bootable pendrive to install boot repair but i think its no longer available.. i dont know.. can someone please help me to fix it?.. thanks in advanced.

Comment: yes.. when i choose install ubuntu it says you already have ubuntu 16.04 and gives options of installing beside it.

Comment: OK - I missed it before. Please be a bit more detailed on what you did so far and how you tried to reinstall `grub` or do the grub-repair.

Comment: when i tried to install boot-repair in ubuntu(pendrive) it says package not found.. also i tried easybcd in windows.. the option to add linux os to windows boot grub is greyed out and i therefore cannot add it..

Comment: From the pendrive you always have to install boot-repair first. Do this by: *sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair*. Then run *sudo apt-get update*, then *sudo apt-get install boot-repair*. Finally, run *boot-repair*. Leave easybcd alone, It's not relevant for a UEFI system.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 16.10 in my pendrive and when i run "sudo apt-get update" i get errors like "404 not found [IP : 91.189.91.23.80]".. is it because of EOL of 16.10.. is there a solution or should i make a pendrive with 16.04

Comment: You have to use current version. Use 16.04 or 18.04 as both as LTS and will last longer.

Comment: i made a 18.04 pendrive and did the boot repair.. still nothing.. system boots straight into windows and also no option of ubuntu in the boot sequence too

Comment: everyone is out of solutions i suppose.. this laptop has given me a hard time already.. i had problems related to it becoming read only and i had to reboot and run manual check.. what should i do?.. should i buy a new a harddisk?.. please reply